# IE 10 and 11 renders in IE 7 mode on intranet site.

Tags: html, internet-explorer, compatibility, microsoft-edge, intranet

I am trying to get IE to render on the latest version for intranet sites, but it keeps defaulting to IE 7 for compatibility. I have this in my Web.config and it still does not work. A meta tag will not work because this is an intranet site (), and I have tried it, also. I have the following in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
   </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions. Also, I do know that you can turn off the compatibility mode in IE settings but this would not work for me as I have 1000s of users that would have to do this individually, which would not be ideal and would be my last choice on how to handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

We have this issue in the organisation that I'm currently working for.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but, from what we've discovered, the 'fallback' to IE7 is a network wide policy set by the IT department. As we all know, getting things like this changed is like getting blood from a stone !

Every set-up is different however so you could try this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

*Directly after* your opening 'head' tag...